# Devise + Patreon OAuth in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have implemented the devise+patreon gem in my Rails application without issues. Now, devise requires an email/password by default when creating a User, but Patreon just uses the oauth integration.

I am wondering, what is the proper strategy to use so that I can migrate the Patreon Oauth users as Devise users, without having to set dummy passwords/emails to allow for validation to go through. I still want to eventually allow users to register via Devise natively, as well as through Patreon.

Is there maybe a known strategy/gem/addition for devise that I may have missed that can easily achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the user email and a lot of other infos ([see here](https://github.com/codewithkristian/omniauth-patreon#auth-hash)) about the user in the login call to patreon's services, but password will remain unknown, you can't just copy & paste a User.